# What transformation is used for EPSG 28409 in GDAL?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I used gdalwarp to convert a raster file in EPSG:4326 to one EPSG:28409 I believe that using this method doesn't apply a full transformation as there is no option to select between the numerous transformation options available for 28409 so the output is shifted from what I am expecting.  Does anyone know about this and if there isn't a way to do it using gdalwarp is there a way to do this using another gdal tool?

Comment: What if you transformed 4326 into one of the transformation options available for 28409, and then converted from there? I would expect a shift if there isn't a transformation that is defined. There is some serious scientific calculations behind transformations.

Comment: Gdal uses the proj library and the source is available for inspection which will solve your problem

Comment: As @IanTurton says, there should be a look-up table that maps 28409 to a PROJ string. Check the string for a +TOWGS84 parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the comments ok so I am relatively new to GDAL, how would I write something to identify the LUT its using for 28409 to be run is OSGeo for example? @enolan from what I can see there is no way to easily select a transformation option for a particular projection using GDAL.  I am guessing it must be possible but I am afraid I don't know how.  What I do know is that I want to use the epsg 1303 transformation of epsg 28409  - how I write that into osgeo is a little beyond me at this stage!